# How to combine last entry in a partition with the first in the next?

Tags: dask

I have a text file that is split into fragments and each fragment compressed separately.

I want to be able to process it as a [Dask bag](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag.html) in a line-by-line fashion. However, the lines are split over the fragment boundaries so after decompression I need to join them back together.

For example, if I originally had:

```
Finland, Finland,  Finland.
The country where I want to be,
Pony trekking or camping,
Or just watching TV,
Finland, Finland, Finland. 
It's the country for me.
You're so near to Russia.
So far from Japan,
Quite a long way from Cairo,
Lots of miles from Vietnam.
```

After decompression I have:

```
Finland, Finland,  Finland.
The country where I want to be,
Pony trekking or camping,
Or just watc
```

```
hing TV,
Finland, Finland, Finland. 
It's the coun
```

```
try for me.
You're so near to Russia.
So far from Japan,
Quite a long
```

```
 way from Cairo,
Lots of miles from Vietnam.
```

A `fold()` or a `reduce()` don't do what I need because it does them all at once, which has a result that is too big to fit in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bag doesn't seem to have the equivalent of map_overlap, which would take items from adjacent partitions.

I think the easiest way to achieve this is to work with the underlying delayed objects, which you can take in pairs:

```
ds = b.to_delayed()  # you get one delayed object per partition
pairs = zip(ds, ds[1:])
dask.compute([process_pair(*pair) for pair in pairs])
```

Where `process_pair` is a function which takes two list-of-lines inputs, but only needs the first line from the second input.

Comment: Yes, using Delayed object seemed to be the way to go. In the end I had to create Delayed objects for most of the loading process too, as there were over a million partitions in the Bag initially.